# How to split a string, including punctuation marks?

Tags: java

I need to split a string (in Java) with punctuation marks being stored in the same array as words:

```
String sentence = "In the preceding examples, classes derived from...";
String[] split = sentence.split(" ");
```

I need split array to be:

```
split[0] - "In"
split[1] - "the"
split[2] - "preceding"
split[3] - "examples"
split[4] - ","
split[5] - "classes"
split[6] - "derived"
split[7] - "from"
split[8] - "..."
```

Is there any elegant solution?

Comment: Are they have to be in the same order as in the sentence?

Comment: should `...` be split as `.` `.` `.` or as `...`?

Comment: Is `?!` or `!?` possible? If so should we split it?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes...

Comment: How clever do you want this to be? Do you want `mother-in-law` to remain one word?

Comment: @storojs72 To whom are you responding?

Comment: '...' must be splitted as '...' as it's a puntuation mark "three dots", but '..' must be splitted as  '.'  '.'

Comment: to you, @Yoda - They must be at the specified positions

Comment: It would be nice if you would show complete requirements. For now it looks like any answer we give here will not be prefect because there is a chance that it will not solve one of the `(special cases...!?)`

Comment: Ok, All of the possible punctuation marks should be stored in splitted array after appropriate words (this is a dot, comma, three dots, question mark, exclamation mark and so one...) from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punctuation

Comment: only punctuation, not dividers, typography and other special symbols

Comment: I'm dealing with usual technical text parsing, so such special cases like (...!?) are not very probable

Comment: `not very probable` != `impossible` so you need to make decision how you want to treat such case.

Comment: Also don't send us to wiki or any other external resource as its data or link can can change any time. Make sure that your question will contain all important details.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet, or do you just want someone to do it for you? Show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Ok, These are the mandatory puntuations: apostrophe, all brackets, colon, comma, dash, three dots, excalmation and question, hyphen, quotation marks, semicolon, slash and backslash

Comment: I tried `StringTokenizer` but it seems to me it doesn't support punctuation storing...

Answer (score 2):

You need a look arounds:

```
String[] split = sentence.split(" ?(?<!\\G)((?<=[^\\p{Punct}])(?=\\p{Punct})|\\b) ?");
```

Look arounds *assert*, but (importantly here) don't *consume* the input when matching.

---

Some test code:

```
String sentence = "Foo bar, baz! Who? Me...";
String[] split = sentence.split(" ?(?<!\\G)((?<=[^\\p{Punct}])(?=\\p{Punct})|\\b) ?");
Arrays.stream(split).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output;

```
Foo
bar
,
baz
!
Who
?
Me
...
```

Comment: It seems to me that's what I was looking for. `Arrays.stream(split).forEach(System.out::println);`
This syntax for Java 8?

Comment: That was also my first idea, but this will not handle case `...` correctly. Also if OP sentence will not be properly formatted like `foo!bar` we will end up with `foo` `!bar`. Actually there are too many important details missed in question to answer it correctly.

Comment: See @Michał Kordas answer

Comment: @Pshemo I got it working properly (with the edge cases I could think of) using the trick you taught me: `\G` :)

Comment: @storojs72 I rewrote my regex to do the whole job properly, without any extra method calls.

Comment: Nice one. BTW `[^\p{Punct}]` can be written as `\P{Punct}` since `\P{Foo}` is negation of `\p{Foo}`.

Comment: I just hope that we will not see any additional requirement which will mean that this approach will stop working correctly.

Comment: @Pshemo I owe you again for learning a cool bit of regex! I searched for the negation for a posix class but didn't find it (I guessed `\p{!Punct}`, but no). Thanks for the lesson :) And thanks for the edit (my copy paste from ideone failed).

Comment: I am not sure if I see a problem or am I creating one, but this regex will not split `(...)` into `(` `...` `)` (that is why despite liking this answer I am still not convinced that `split` is right way to go here).

Answer (score 1):

You may try by replacing triple dots with ellipsis character first:

```
    String sentence = "In the preceding examples, classes derived from...";
    String[] split = sentence.replace("...", "…").split(" +|(?=,|\\p{Punct}|…)");
```

Afterwards you can leave it as it is or convert it back by running `replace("…", "...")` on entire array.

Comment: But this way we will not get in results triple dots but ellipsis. And what in case where there will be string containing `...` and `…`? We will not be able to see which one was there originally (there can be scenarios where such knowledge could be important).

Comment: Regarding first - please see last sentence in my answer. Regarding second, you can always replace it temporarily with any unique string or even UUID.

Comment: OK you are right, replacing `...` with unique string can work (assuming that we will generate it for each text parsed which doesn't seems very natural in solution for this kind of problem). I agree on that. Anyway to make your answer correct you also need to add mechanism for handling splitting *after* punctuation like `"foo" bar should also be split not only before `"` in `foo|"` but also after `"` in `"|foo`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this method will do what you want

```
public static List<String> split(String str) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)|(\\.{3})|[^\\s]");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        list.add(matcher.group());
    }
    return list;
}
```

It will split a string into

1. Consecutive word characters
2. Ellipsis `...`
3. Anything else separated by a space

For this example

```
"In the preceding examples, classes.. derived from... Hello, World! foo!bar"
```

The list will be

```
[0] In
[1] the
[2] preceding
[3] examples
[4] ,
[5] classes
[6] .
[7] .
[8] derived
[9] from
[10] ...
[11] Hello
[12] ,
[13] World
[14] !
[15] foo
[16] !
[17] bar
```

Answer (score 1):

For now I will say that easiest and probably cleanest way to achieve what you want is to focus on finding data you want in array, rather than finding place to split your text on.

I am saying this because `split` introduces a lot of problems like for instance:

- `split(" +|(?=\\p{Punct})");` will split only on space and ***before*** punctuation character, which means that text like `"abc" def` will be split into `"abc` `"` `def`. So as you see it doesn't split ***after*** `"` in `"abc`.
- previous problem can be solved easily by adding another `|(?<=\\p{Punct})` condition like `split(" +|(?=\\p{Punct})|(?<=\\p{Punct})")`, but we still didn't solve all of your problems because of `...`. So we need to figure out way to prevent splitting in between these dots `.|.|.`.

  - To do it we could try excluding `.` from `\p{Punct}` and trying to handle it separately but this would make our regex quite complex.
  - Other way to do it could be replacing `...` with some unique string, adding this string in our `split` logic and after all replacing it back to `...` in our result array. But this approach would also require from us to know what string will never be possible to have in your text, so we will need to generate it each time we parse text.
- Another possible problem is that pre-java-8 regex engine will generate empty element at start of your result array if punctuation will be first character like `"`. So in Java 7 `"foo" bar` string split on `(?=\p{Punct)` will result in `[ , "foo, " bar]` elements. To avoid this problem you would need to add regex like `(?!^)` to prevent splitting at start of the string.

Anyway these solutions looks overly complex.

---

So instead of `split` method consider using `find` method from `Matcher` class and focus on what you want to have in result array.

Try using pattern like this one: `[.]{3}|\p{Punct}|[\S&&\P{Punct}]+"`

- `[.]{3}` will match `...`
- `\p{Punct}` will match single punctuation character which according to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) is one of `` !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~ ``

  `!` `"` `#` `$` `%` `&` `'` `(` `)` `*` `+` `,` `-` `.` `/` `:` `;` `<` `=` `>` `?` `@` `[` `\` `]` `^` `_` `` ` `` `{` `|` `}` `~`
- `[\S&&\P{Punct}]+` will match one or more characters which are

  - `\S` not whitespaces
  - `&&` and
  - `\P{Punct}` not punctuation characters (`\P{foo}` is negation of `\p{foo}`).

Demo:

```
String sentence = "In (the) preceding examples, classes derived from...";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[.]{3}|\\p{Punct}|[\\S&&\\P{Punct}]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(sentence);
while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Output:

```
In
(
the
)
preceding
examples
,
classes
derived
from
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could sanitize the string replacing, say "," with " ,", and so on for all punctuation marks you care to distinguish.

In the particular case of "..." you can do:

```
// there can be series of dots
sentence.replace(".", " .").replace(". .", "..")
```

Then you split.

EDIT: replaced single quotes with double quotes.

Comment: This is not correct Java syntax. It should all be written with double quotes instead.

Comment: This contains a bug.  As written it returns: `[In, the, preceding, examples,, classes, derived, from, .., .]`.  Doing the last replace one more time will fix it but the more elegant solution to change the last replace to: `.replace(". . .", "...")`:

Comment: Also notice this did nothing to split the comma properly.

Answer (score 0):

For your particular case the two main challenges are the ordering (e.g. first punctuation and then word or the other way around) and the `...` punctuation.

The rest you can easily implement it using

```
\p{Punct}
```

like this:

```
Pattern.compile("\p{Punct}");
```

Regarding the two mentioned challenges:

1.Ordering:
You can try the following:

```
private static final Pattern punctuation = Pattern.compile("\\p{Punct}");
private static final Pattern word = Pattern.compile("\\w");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sentence = "In the preceding examples, classes derived from...";
    String[] split = sentence.split(" ");
    List<String> result = new LinkedList<>();

    for (String s : split) {
        List<String> withMarks = splitWithPunctuationMarks(s);
        result.addAll(withMarks);
    }
}

private static void List<String> splitWithPunctuationMarks(String s) {
    Map<Integer, String> positionToString = new TreeMap<>();
    Matcher punctMatcher = punctuation.matcher(s);
    while (punctMatcher.find()) {
        positionToString.put(punctMatcher.start(), punctMatcher.group())
    }
    Matcher wordMatcher = // ... same as before
    // Then positionToString.values() will contain the 
    // ordered words and punctuation characters.
}
```

2. `...` You can try to look back for previous occurrences of the `.` character at (currentIndex - 1) every time you find it.

Answer (score 0):

another example here. this solution probably works for all combinations.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        String sentence = "In the preceding examples, classes derived from...";
        List<String> list = splitWithPunctuation(sentence);
        System.out.println(list);
    }

    public static List<String> splitWithPunctuation(String sentence) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^a-zA-Z\\d\\s]+)");
        String[] split = sentence.split(" ");
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String s : split) {
            Matcher matcher = p.matcher(s);
            boolean found = false;
            int i = 0;
            while (matcher.find()) {
                found = true;
                list.add(s.substring(i, matcher.start()));
                list.add(s.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end()));
                i = matcher.end();
            }

            if (found) {
                if (i < s.length())
                    list.add(s.substring(i, s.length()));
            } else
                list.add(s);
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
In
the
preceding
examples
,
classes
derived
from 
...
```

A more complex example:

```java
String sentence = "In the preced^^^in## examp!les, classes derived from...";
List<String> list = splitWithPunctuation(sentence);
System.out.println(list);
```

Output:

```
In
the
preced
^^^
in
##
examp
!
les
,
classes
derived
from
...
```